# Término que se refiere a definir una palabra utilizando la misma palabra

Tags: selección-de-palabras, vocabulario, identificación-de-término, recurso-retórico

No recuerdo cómo se llama cuando en la definición de una palabra empleas el mismo término de modo que la definición queda vacía de contenido. ¿Alguien lo sabe?

Ejemplo:

> ¿Qué es un instrumento? Un *instrumento* es un *instrumento* que  hace música.

Comment: No sé si técnicamente tiene un nombre, pues eso en realidad no es una definición (no aclara nada). Yo siempre las he oído llamar, ["Definición de Perogrullo"](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Sh54Lwn) o ["Perogrullada"](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Sh3Pvxz). Perogrullo es un personaje ficticio a quien se atribuye presentar obviedades de manera sentenciosa (tipo "Un instrumento es un instrumento"). Diría que quizá la definición es **auto**-algo (autorreferida o similar), pero es que realmente tampoco es una definición. Tampoco es una "definición circular".

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con @Diego, tal como explico en el comentario a la respuesta aceptada (no es una "definición circular" según el DLE). Creo que la pregunta no está bien definida. Parece que el ejemplo debería ser "Un _instrumento_ musical es un _instrumento_ que hace música". La [definición de la RAE](https://dle.rae.es/?id=LoJdDcs#9PfdYLK) no es muy distinta, solo cambia "instrumento" por "objeto". Lo más cercano que se me ocurre es [tautología](https://dle.rae.es/?id=ZGVxTo2): "Acumulación reiterativa de un significado ya aportado desde el primer término de una enunciación".

Comment: ¿ *Sinécdoque* ?

Comment: Hay unas opciones que describen el uso de, por ejemplo, "instrumento" para "instrumento musical": - sinécdoque
- [*totum pro parte*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totum_pro_parte)

Comment: Se trata de una tautología.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una **definición circular** es una definición que supone una comprensión anterior del término que es definido.

> Por ejemplo, podemos definir el "roble" como un árbol que crece a partir de una bellota, y después definimos la "bellota" como la nuez producida por el roble. Para alguien que no sepa qué árboles son robles o qué nueces son bellotas, la definición no es de utilidad.
>
> (Fuente: [wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definici%C3%B3n_circular))

Comment: La [cuarta acepción del adj. _circular_](https://dle.rae.es/?id=9JaWQWh|9JbEPdR) dice: "Dicho de un razonamiento o de una definición: Que relaciona **dos** elementos que se explican **recíprocamente**". El caso de la pregunta es ligeramente distinto: apelar al mismo vocablo definido (aplicando el término matemático correspondiente, de forma **reflexiva**, no a través de dos términos **recíprocos**). De todas formas, igual la RAE debería ampliar la definición, porque la verdad es que [se usa también en ese sentido](https://filosofiadelavida.wordpress.com/2016/05/26/la-definicion/).

Answer (score 1):

Podría considerarse una "falacia de definición". Ver [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falacias_de_definici%C3%B3n).

Answer (score 1):

**Tautología**, básicamente es definir algo usando las mismas palabras, tipo "yo soy el que soy"

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/24866)

Answer (score 1):

En mi experiencia, el término más claro y de uso más general es **definición circular**, como ya se ha señalado correctamente. Y por supuesto, como también apuntan algunos comentarios, una definición circular no es una definición en sentido propio.
Por otro lado la palabra **tautología** no debe utilizarse en este contexto. Las tautologías no son definiciones per se, juegan un papel fundamental en la lógica y al contrario de lo expresado por la definición, algo estrecha y casi obsoleta de la RAE, proveen un caudal de información, si bien todas son lógicamente equivalentes. Además, las tautologías no son necesariamente circulares, ni autorreferentes.
En lógica una **definición impredicativa** (palabra que no recoge la RAE) es un tipo de definición autorreferente, de carácter cercano a la definición circular, pero de una naturaleza técnica que no cabe discutir aquí. La menciono porque de una manera informal,  una definición circular es un tipo de definición impredicativa,  esto es no aporta elementos a la clase de objetos que pretende definir.