# ¿Es "avío" una buena alternativa a "kit"?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, selección-de-palabras, palabras-raras

Leo en Twitter:

> Una lectora amabilísima me sugiere que digamos AVÍO en lugar de KIT y la verdad es que me parece una idea genial: avío de supervivencia y avío de maquillaje (nunca "kit del puchero ").
>
> <sub>Lola Pons Rodríguez, [13 febrero de 2019](https://twitter.com/Nosolodeyod/status/1095753987498889218)</sub>

No conocía esta palabra así que miré en el DLE y tachán:

> [**avío**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=4a5NnJb)
>   De aviar<sup>1</sup>.
>
> 1. m. Prevención, apresto.
>   2. m. Entre pastores y gente de campo, provisión que se lleva al hato para alimentarse durante el tiempo que se tarda en volver al pueblo o cortijo.
>   3. m. Conveniencia, interés o provecho personal. Ir a su avío. Hacer su avío.
>   4. m. Bol., El Salv., Méx. y Perú. Préstamo en dinero o efectos, que se hace a los labradores, ganaderos o mineros.
>   **5. m. pl. Utensilios necesarios para algo. *Avíos de escribir, de coser, de afeitar*.**

Vista la definición de la 5.ª entrada, parece que puede ser útil como traducción. Sin embargo, que aparezca tan abajo en la lista de entradas, incluso por debajo de las entradas regionales, me hace pensar que no se usa demasiado.

Entonces: ¿es buena opción? ¿Se usa actualmente en algún caso?

Comment: Avío puede funcionar pero no es común. Nosotros usamos "equipo" en los mismos casos p. ej: "Equipo de carretera" que contiene herramientas y botiquín para los viajes en carro. "Equipo de supervivencia",  etc.

Comment: Una alternativa que aprendí en tierras manchegas: _**[apechusques](http://dle.rae.es/?id=378TgnU)**_.

Comment: Yo siempre he usado *equipo*. Me preguntaría en qué país *no* se usa la verdad. De ser la 5.ª lo será por ser un uso en plural, que normalmente va debajo la acepciones que se usan sin distinción.

Comment: No obstante, *avíos* hace una referencia en plural (así entiendo yo que cada avío como una cosa en el equipo). *Kit* es singular, así que empleando *avíos*, ¿cuál sería la traducción de *kits*?

Comment: Tu pregunta quedaría mejor, a mi aviso, con dos o tres ejemplos que muestren cómo usas *kit*. // Creo que *equipo* funciona bien.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para mí no es una buena alternativa. Comparto lo que expones en la pregunta sobre el uso de `Avío`: técnicamente correcta, pero poco práctica, debido a lo poco común del término.

Yo favorecería [estuche](https://dle.rae.es/?id=H1a2W0o) que no es solo

> 1. m. **Caja o envoltura** para guardar ordenadamente un objeto o varios; como joyas, instrumentos de cirugía, etc.

es decir, el continente, si no también el contenido (tercera acepción).

> 3. m. Conjunto de utensilios que se guardan en el estuche.

Decir "Estuche de supervivencia" y "Estuche de maquillaje" me parece mejor opción que "avío de supervivencia" y "avío de maquillaje". Comparando ambas entradas no son tan distintas.

> (Avío) Utensilios necesarios para algo
>
> (Estuche) Conjunto de utensilios que se guardan en el estuche.

Parecería que la primera deja más claro para qué son los utensilios, pero hemos de recodar que la tercera entrada de `estuche` no es realmente una [definición circular](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/28546/5481) cuando decimos de qué tipo es el estuche (de supervivencia o maquillaje), lo que deja muy clara la finalidad de los utensilios.